# SymmetricDS - function SYM_HEX is not defined

Tags: mysql, database, firebird, symmetricds

I am using SymmetricDS 3.11.8 to replicate and synchronise a Firebird database to a MySQL database. I am using Firebird 2.5.

I have successfully been able to do this with [the demo](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.11/html/tutorials.html) given by SymmetricDS and my own demo tables while learning the SymmetricDS [configuration instructions](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.11/html/user-guide.html#_introduction). I am now trying to synchronise a specific table an a pre-existing database, called STK_STOCKITEM.

I am getting the error:

> Resource Exception. invalid request BLR at offset 6781; function
>   SYM_HEX is not defined; module name or entrypoint could not be found
>   [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544343]

I did *install* the SYM_UDF.dll in the Firebird UDF directory and when I create the Sym Tables when running `symadmin --engine omni-000 create-sym-tables` I see that the it uses the UDF:

```
[omni-000] - Firebird21SymmetricDialect - Installing SymmetricDS database object:
                                          declare external function sym_hex blob
                                          returns cstring(32660) 
                                          free_it entry_point 'sym_hex' module_name 'sym_udf'
[omni-000] - Firebird21SymmetricDialect - Just installed sym_hex
```

At the moment I am not sure whether the `function SYM_HEX is not defined` is the root of the problem or something else, since before that error I get the following, initial error:

```
[omni-000] - V10Transaction - Commit not completed, state was COMMITTING
java.lang.RuntimeException: Commit not completed
        at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Transaction.commit(V10Transaction.java:94)
        at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.internalCommit(FBManagedConnection.java:640)
...
...
[omni-000] - Firebird21SymmetricDialect - Failed to create trigger: create trigger SYM_ON_I_FOR_STK_STCKTM_MN for "STK_STOCKITEM" after insert position 5 as                                  
   begin

     if (1=1 and rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION','sync_triggers_disabled') is null) then
...
...
```

[**Here is the full log output**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhgv4kyb5mmlsja/symmetric%20-%20Copy.log?dl=0). The log output starts when I created the sym tables and the error after I started the symmetric instance. If anyone is interested in trying to reproduce the problem, [**here is the (non-proprietary, generic) database containing the STK_STOCKITEM table**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1nnsaq7qzam435/SA_DEMO_COMPANY.FDB?dl=0) .

Comment: Can you use the UDF outside of SymmetricDS?

`select sym_hex(STOCKIMAGE) from STK_STOCKITEM;`

Comment: UDF may be disabled for that folder in `firebird.conf`. There also can be architecture mismatch, like Win32 DLL and Win64 Firebird or vice versa. It may also be that you did not restart Firebird after first error, so it just "remembers" there was no DLL. // After checking and fixing those, use database IDEs like IBExpert Personal or FlameRobin or others, connect to the database and try to call the UDF from SQL console, see if it works. If not - use SysInternals Process Monitor filtering for File I/O and Firebird Server exe. Call the UDF from SQL and see which disk activity happenned & failed

Comment: What is the bitness of your Firebird install, and what is the bitness of the DLL you put in the UDF folder of your Firebird install? Is UDF access even allowed by the configuration, and is the folder you put the DLL in the list of allowed folders?